# Nginx permission denied for tmp directory (with correct user)

Tags: nginx, wordpress

Whenever I submit a long post from within wordpress, I get the following error:

```
2013/06/04 03:04:19 [crit] 12248#0: *491 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000008" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

It works fine if the post isn't that long, but submitting a long one throws a 500 error on the front end, and this in my error log file :/

I tried googling and nothing is much help, other than to change the user or something

Right now I already have...

`/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body` owned by www:www (nginx) and set to 700 permissions

Comment: Set it to 770..

Comment: that wasn't it. the problem was the parent directories however needed to be set to www:www (same permissions, 0700)

Comment: That would also do it.

Comment: After upgrade these directories were set to user nginx:nginx on my system ... so set chown -R and chgrp -R them back to the original user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command to fix the permission of nginx folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/lib/nginx/tmp
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem on Amazon Linux EC2. Running the below command helped to solve it:

```
chown -Rf ec2-user:ec2-user /var/lib/nginx
```

Previously it was owned by the root user and changing it to ec2-user worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: **DO NOT DO THIS**. If this fixes your issue then **YOU HAVE  A MAJOR SECURITY ISSUE**. This directory is intended for use by the webserver UID. You should NEVER run a webserver under a normal user account (except in some rare edge cases).